# HttpClient returning 403 on Docker hosted .NET 8 application

Tags: c#, .net, docker, httpclient

I am a new adopter of Docker. Been loving it so far, but ran into an issue that I can't seem to figure out myself.

I'm trying to do a HTTP call (C#/.NET8) to a website using a proxy and some other settings. You can check some example code below.

When I run this without Docker it all seems to run fine. But when I run this exact same code in a docker container, I receive 403 errors. It never succeeds even once.

I changed some settings in the dockerfile, and also removed the proxy, default request headers, etc. But nothing seems to work.

```
var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
var handler = new HttpClientHandler {
    Proxy = new WebProxy {
        Address = new Uri(""),
        BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
            userName: "",
            password: "")
    },
    CookieContainer = cookieContainer,
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.All
};

var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en,en-US;q=0.9,nl;q=0.8,nl-NL;q=0.7");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/plain"));
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", RandomUserAgent.RandomUa.RandomUserAgent);

return await httpClient.GetStringAsync("");
```

My Docker file is just a standard generated dockerfile from Visual Studio:

```
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DockerHttpClient/DockerHttpClient.csproj", "DockerHttpClient/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./DockerHttpClient/./DockerHttpClient.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DockerHttpClient"
RUN dotnet build "./DockerHttpClient.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./DockerHttpClient.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerHttpClient.dll"]
```

The HTTP result is as follows.

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetStringAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Program.<>c.<<<Main>$>b__0_0>d.MoveNext() in C:\Projects\_SYMSON\ViSoftTesting\DockerHttpClient\Program.cs:line 53
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.<ExecuteTaskOfString>g__ExecuteAwaited|134_0(Task`1 task, HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: text/plain
Host: localhost:49232
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en,en-US;q=0.9,nl;q=0.8,nl-NL;q=0.7
Cookie: ai_user=/StHPwvvgiqgP/x0cSb8R2|2023-08-20T16:06:23.127Z; _ga=GA1.1.1380647519.1692647091; GuidedTourCompleted=True; .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.p_sxoDt8eYU=CfDJ8KKHrAOYPhJDsp3zFKTeIYnWmHkOzJZYZDX3NZXjeu3RQSNKPVLpArpifjtdsegqMXbocwJWKopH-bsA9udajzvczF3mSZqvRM2CEWm_D_B3tjaSVamIl5oOfyiy5FbcR_bA92K4ZjIQpJ5ssyp89yQ; dark=1; .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.yNvmbL6U2i8=CfDJ8KKHrAOYPhJDsp3zFKTeIYlhYON4p5e0-XTemoSIl-F1CuXyZ8szX4A7pkBv6UadIRCl3bdHD9lvJzljaIK0GyW1STH6xPFIoFAv5phn8gOOqag3wQPBNEz_3iSC-B1KoJilrNKSfqmBl1Q-RrCOWZo; _ga_8H6DESL7W3=GS1.1.1701114193.7.1.1701114732.59.0.0; .AspNetCore.Cookies=CfDJ8KKHrAOYPhJDsp3zFKTeIYmofL3_E9cuLnSe4u3UPt5Rpbygfhnk3FQMB0rXFFtVX10JVj6FxV_ehbwy7SOv2wmLa1sRj8DPJgI5uit_t4VpO28sfLG-EsJNHgNKYymJ77ESYMkNlLwVo-fCV70iamZazc6WI3768Fo8WPz75TN3TGGhiZN09H1k9wKDDWpB7M_02hxXVOJL0z9QQPHA4TuIdVWazO4LKraNc4RpOYzfyeSIj8-EE2T-YyuJbQdl-h1qiCWSLo3b_MbUJKLWHrOuSfC27AOE17WoWF_R04_msnseCD6-RIh8JTkLRzlhcZrQyLM7MbDNAkeoJTLYkXNOMmM7UXzoa5SMFHoujFw6quyFfSUUFbc8QcGZlHwWeEfW_Gq0pGxjdhQV7ssmFqSqFs2KXYegp04exljutk4ImXQmE7OZYyOd_B71HxEr9He0U75SQIMo-1ab0ITmR0N1AVTDuXxD7FiyO8tNFsLS; .AspNetCore.Culture=c%3Den-US%7Cuic%3Den-US
Referer: https://localhost:49232/swagger/index.html
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="119", "Chromium";v="119", "Not?A_Brand";v="24"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-dest: empty
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks! :)

Comment: What address are you trying to call? your URI is empty

Comment: I emptied it. But an example would be https://www.douglas.nl/nl/p/1069044295?variant=019719

Comment: So you want to call a website with a docker container but the host is proxied?

https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/ maybe this is something you want to have a look in

Comment: @SirOneOfMany Even without the proxy it is not working. Also, I want to be able to set the proxy within the code. Not in a docker configuration. It has to be set dynamically.

Comment: Do you at least get some error messages you can provide?

Comment: @SirOneOfMany I modified my original post. It now has the HTTP request result from the 403. That is the only thing I get.

Comment: I suggest to use `GetAsync` and log the response content and headers before status code check. There may be nothing for 403 but still. Try incresing the log levels for http client so that you get to see the details of what's happening. possibly try against a server under your control, we don't know what checks are in place on external sites. And once you have the smallest possible repro, post it here. In full.

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek I tried to make it as simple as possible: https://github.com/Thovenaar/ViSoftTesting I also tried this code on Docker with different websites. But as of right now it only seems to fail for this specific website. They might have some anti-bot detection in place?

Comment: Ok, then capture the request you are sending from your machine that works and the one sent from docker, try to reproduce the problem on your machine outside of .NET (i.e. using curl or postman) based on the docket request and you will find the root cause. Then it may or may not be caused by something in .NET and your question becomes "how do I send request like this in .NET on Linux" which is answerable. It may also become a question for that site's administrator at which point this is probably a wrong forum.

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek Not really sure how to capture traffic from my Docker container. I've discovered that running a curl command from the docker terminal seems to work fine. I even created a HTTP client + request purely from this curl request. However, still no success.. I'm continuing my search!

Comment: It should be possible to log HttpClient requests in the application. See [logging section of Make HTTP requests using IHttpClientFactory in ASP.NET Core article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-8.0#logging)

Comment: I logged two http requests, one for the not working URL and one for a working URL:
https://pastebin.com/c7nxZCK6 and https://pastebin.com/hcZezFj8 @ZdeněkJelínek Can you see anything wrong with it?

Comment: Not at a first glance, no. If you reconstruct the failing request in curl on the docker instance, does it work?

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek Yes I copied the exact curl command from my Chrome in Windows and tried it in the docker terminal, that worked as well. It really seems to have something to do with the .NET app..

Comment: What I meant is take the headers from the .net log and hand-craft request from that. If that does not reproduce, next step would be to use a MITM proxy such as Charles to observe the raw request from .net and curl and compare that. If there is no observable difference, then that is strange indeed.

Comment: @Tho-venaar did you end up finding the problem here? I'm having the same issue. My .NET 7 containers work but the .NET 8 (the request sender) always 403s to the .NET 7 ones